# SQL Autocomplete on Aptana

Tags: sql, autocomplete, aptana

Is it possible to have syntax highlighting for SQL in Aptana. Also, is there anyway to add autocomplete for SQl, eclipse has this feature but it does not have php autocomplete.

Comment: Does Eclipse have PHP Autocomplete when you add the Aptana plugin?

Comment: Yes, thats a better solution